# My face is greasy VS My face is oily

Tags: word-usage, grammar

It was a hot day yesterday.

I went out all the day afternoon to send a parcel, paid bill and picked up my son.

When I went to home.

> My face is greasy.
>
> My face is oily.

What word should I used if my face emmited too much oil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, your face is *greasy*.

If you talk about *oily* skin, most listeners would first think about the general condition where your skin always produces a bit too much sebum, making you prone to acne.

In that sense, "oily skin" is the opposite of "dry skin", where your skin produces too little sebum and can feel tense and wrinkly or flaky.

But I probably would have used the term "sweaty", indicating the side effects of exercise or exertion, albeit not exactly the same as "greasy".